# Cannot remove or stop docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-command

I run a web using `sudo docker compose up` but it has a container that recreate infinitely. Therefor, I want to remove that container and build it again, but when I run `sudo docker container rm f8df3e233d00` (f8df3e233d00 is ID of container that i listed by `sudo docker ps`), it does nothing, just break line and do nothing.

[image]

How can I remove that container?

Comment: You're stuck with it forever! Unless you try `-f`, for `force`. And if that doesn't work, try restarting the Docker service.

Comment: I tried `sudo docker container rm -f f8df3e233d00` and `sudo docker restart f8df3e233d00`, it is same issue with my question issue

Comment: Not restarting the container, restarting the service. Depending on what OS you're on, that could be in the GUI, or `sudo service docker restart`, or `sudo systemctl restart docker`.

Comment: i restart service and install again successfully. Thank you